# How to add a user's public IP to the X-Forwarded-For header using SvelteKit and TypeScript?

Tags: ip-address, sveltekit, public

I'm developing a web application with SvelteKit and TypeScript. During the login process, I aim to send the logged-in user's public IP information in the headers.

```
event.locals.clientIP = event.getClientAddress();
```

`event.getClientAddress()` just return local ip.

How can I correctly add the logged-in user's public IP to the X-Forwarded-For header?

### Additional Info:

I'd prefer not to use external APIs to fetch the public IP due to potential security vulnerabilities. Is there an alternative method to obtain the IP?

Comment: This question lacks information about your web server configuration and is unanswerable. Please edit the question to include **all** relevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get the client IP on server side:

+page.server.ts:

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').RequestHandler} */
export async function load(event) {
    return { ip: event.getClientAddress() };
}
```

And access it on client side:

+page.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    export let data: PageData;
</script>

{#if data?.ip}
    <p>ip to test: {data.ip}</p>
{/if}
```

Note that when running on localhost, you'll get your local IP, but after deploying to production, then the user IP will be returned.